# IRS overpayment interest - Is it interest on what I pay in taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, interest, irs

I have seen that the IRS pays overpayment interest rates that seem to range from 3-8%. When I see these rates are they related to what I pay in taxes? I.e. if I vastly overpay my taxes does this mean I will see return rates of 3-8% interest on what I overpaid in?

Example:
http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/n746.pdf

Comment: From the last page section called "Status of Your Account", I think you will see a check mailed back to you with a tiny bit of interest, but I would let an expert answer.

Answer (score 1):

The rates have nothing to do with your tax rate.  The rate in those tables is [the federal short-term rate, plus 3%](http://www.smbiz.com/sbrl004.html).

As for using overpayment of taxes as a high-yield savings account, let us know how that goes. :)

Comment: Am I missing something? 6-11% (with the +3%) is pretty good right? Your last sentence makes me wonder if I'm missing something obvious :)

Comment: It seems those are for estimated taxes only not withholding unless I am reading it wrong.  So if you have them withhold an extra 200 a month you would not get interest on the 2400 return in april.